# How to semi_join two dataframes by string column with one being colon-separated

Tags: r, dplyr, fuzzyjoin, anti-join, semi-join

I have two dataframes, `dfa` and `dfb`:

```
dfa <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC16", "MUC2", "MET", "FAT1", "TERT"),
  id = c(1:5)
)

dfb <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC1", "MET; BLEP", "MUC21", "FAT", "TERT"),
  id = c(6:10)
)
```

which look like this:

```
> dfa
  gene_name id
1     MUC16  1
2      MUC2  2
3       MET  3
4      FAT1  4
5      TERT  5

> dfb
  gene_name id
1      MUC1  6
2 MET; BLEP  7
3     MUC21  8
4       FAT  9
5      TERT 10
```

`dfa` is my genes of interest list: I want to keep the `dfb` rows where they appear, minding the digits (`MUC1` is **not** `MUC16`). My `new_df` should look like this:

```
> new_df
  gene_name id
1 MET; BLEP  7
2      TERT 10
```

My problem is that the regular `dplyr::semi_join()` does exact matches, which doesn't take into account the fact that `dfb$gene_names` can contain genes separated with `"; "`. Meaning that with this example, `"MET"` is not retained.

I tried to look into `fuzzyjoin::regex_semi_join`, but I can't make it do what I want...

A tidyverse solution would be welcome. (Maybe with `stringr`?!)

**EDIT:** Follow-up question...

How would I go about to do the reciprocal `anti_join`? Simply changing `semi_join` to `anti_join` in this method doesn't work because the row `MET; BLEP` is present when it shouldn't be...

Adding a `filter(gene_name == new_col)` after the `anti_join` works with the provided simple dataset, but if I twist it a little like this:

```
dfa <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC16", "MUC2", "MET", "FAT1", "TERT"),
  id = c(1:5)
)

dfb <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC1", "MET; BLEP", "MUC21; BLOUB", "FAT", "TERT"),
  id = c(6:10)
)
```

...then it doesn't anymore. Here and in my real-life dataset, `dfa` doesn't contain semicolons, it's only one column of individual gene names. But `dfb` contains a lot of information, and multiple combinations of semicolons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally managed to make `fuzzyjoin::regex_joins` do what I want. It was ridiculously simple, I just had to tweak my `dfa` filter list:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

# add "\b" regex expression before/after each gene of the list to filtrate from
# (to search for whole words)
dfa$gene_name <- paste0("\\b", dfa$gene_name, "\\b")

# to keep genes from dfb that are present in the dfa filter list
dfb %>% 
  regex_semi_join(dfa, by = c(gene_name = "gene_name"))

# to exclude genes from dfb that are present in the dfa filter blacklist
dfb %>% 
  regex_anti_join(dfa, by = c(gene_name = "gene_name"))
```

One drawback though: it's quite slow...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `seperate_rows()` to split the dataframe before joining. Note that if `BLEP` existed in dfa, it would result in a duplicate, which is why distinct is used

```
dfa <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC16", "MUC2", "MET", "FAT1", "TERT"),
  id = c(1:5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dfb <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC1", "MET; BLEP", "MUC21", "FAT", "TERT"),
  id = c(6:10),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


library(tidyverse)

dfb%>%
  mutate(new_col = gene_name)%>%
  separate_rows(new_col,sep = "; ")%>%
  semi_join(dfa,by = c("new_col" = "gene_name"))%>%
  select(gene_name,id)%>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: This could also do the job `... separate_rows(new_col,sep = "; ") %>%
  filter(new_col %in% dfa$gene_name) %>% ...` instead of joining.

Comment: Thanks @Sada93 and @AntoniosK, your answers both work!

@Sada93, if you modify `separate_rows(new_col,sep = ";")%>% mutate(new_col = gsub(" ","",new_col))%>%` to become only `separate_rows(new_col,sep = "; ")%>%` I'll be glad to accept your answer!

Comment: Follow-up question: how would I go about to do the reciprocal `anti_join`? Simply changing `semi_join` to `anti_join` in this method doesn't work because the row `MET; BLEP` is present when it shouldn't be... @AntoniosK

Comment: You can add a `filter(gene_name == new_col)` after the `anti_join` but I think this would only work if `dfa` is not represented by semicolon notation. If dfa can also contain semicolons we would need something fancier.

Comment: It works with the provided simple dataset, but if I twist it a little like this: `dfa <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC16", "MUC2", "MET", "FAT1", "TERT"),
  id = c(1:5)
)

dfb <- data.frame(
  gene_name = c("MUC1", "MET; BLEP", "MUC21; BLOUB", "FAT", "TERT"),
  id = c(6:10)
)` then it doesn't anymore. Here and in my real-life dataset, `dfa` doesn't contain semicolons, it's only one column of individual gene names. But `dfb` contains a lot of information, and multiple combinations of semicolons...

Comment: Should the previous comment be its own question/post?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `stringr` and `purrr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfb %>%
 mutate(gene_name_list = str_split(gene_name, "; ")) %>%
 mutate(gene_of_interest = map_lgl(gene_name_list, some, ~ . %in% dfa$gene_name)) %>%
 filter(gene_of_interest == TRUE) %>%
 select(gene_name, id)
```